# How to modify locally stored objects in Codename One - Best Practices

Tags: local-storage, codenameone

How do I modify or add to a previously stored object?  If I had a hashtable called "people" which currently maintains 100 hashtables representing individual people, how would I add a profile image and a favorite quote to one of these "people". I see example of accessing the top level of local storage, but I can't seem to find anything about accessing nested members directly.  Obviously this could be done by reading the hashtable object, modifying the desired data and rewriting the object, but this seems too inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage is a filesystem like structure designed for smaller things, when you write an object you are effectively serializing which is good for smaller elements. You can either break down the data to smaller "batches" to make it more efficient so instead of writing the whole data to one storage entry.

Alternatively you can use SQLite or CloudObject to store elements, both of which are covered extensively in the [developer guide](http://codenameone.com/developer-guide.html), [how do I](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html) & [course](http://udemy.com/codenameone101/).

Comment: Thank you Shai.  In my research regarding Codename One and storage, it is suggested that SQLite is not recommended due to the lack of support on all devices.  This is why I was using the Storage class instead of SQLite.  Due to the limitations of Storage for my purposes I might need to revisit that decision.

Comment: From the developer guide: "Most new devices contain one version of sqlite or another; sqlite is a very lightweight SQL
database designed for embedding into devices. For portability we recommend avoiding SQL altogether since it is both fragmented between devices (different sqlite versions) and
isn’t supported on other devices." https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Docs/CodenameOneDevelopersGuide.html

Comment: SQLite has some minor incompatibilities between platforms and is currently only supported on iOS, Android & RIM. It doesn't currently work on Windows Phone. If you are interested in braving these incompatibilities and feel comfortable with SQL it can work out nicely for you.